# Mapbox GL JS line layer rendering issue on mobile

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

I have a local vector tile service set up which serves vector tile data in MapBox protobuf format. I also wrote a simple JS client using Mapbox GL JS to display the vector tile data.

Everything is rendered fine on my desktop browser. However, when I opened the client app on mobile browsers (various devices), some of them have a rendering issue - looks like something is wrong with z-level of the line layer (screens attached at bottom).

For simplification, I will post code displaying only the protobuf tiles with lines at tile borders, horizontal lines and vertical lines. The issue still appears, same as with 'real' map data.

Issue is not browser specific. It was spotted both on mobile chrome and firefox on 2 phones: Xiaomi Redmi Note2, and some Samsung with very high screen resolution.
Rendering was ok on a Xperia Z1 with Chrome.
Rendering is ok on desktop browsers.

One more thing - I checked the vector tile example from MapBox examples page and it renders ok everywhere.

**Question(s):**

Maybe someone with MapBox protobuf / GL JS lib experience have any idea what might be wrong?
Maybe the styles are missing some setting...
or the GL JS library has some not-obvious requirements towards the vector tile pbf data it's being fed with?

**Client app code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Mapbox test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mapbox-gl.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_TOKEN';

    var tileBorders = {
        "id": "tile-borders",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "debug-grid",
        "source-layer": "debug_line_red",
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#f00",
            "line-width": 1
        }
    };
    var debugLineGreen = {
        "id": "debug-green",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "debug-grid",
        "source-layer": "debug_line_green",
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#0f0",
            "line-width": 1
        }
    };
    var debugLineBlue = {
        "id": "debug-blue",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "debug-grid",
        "source-layer": "debug_line_blue",
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "#00f",
            "line-width": 1
        }
    };


    var style = {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "debug-grid": {
                "type": "vector",
                "minzoom": 4,
                "tiles": ["http://localhost:18080/grid/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]
            }
        },
        // using mapbox glyph and sprite resources
        "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
        "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/bright-v8",
        "layers": [tileBorders, debugLineGreen, debugLineBlue]
    };

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: style,
        zoom: 13,
        center: [19.447303, 51.753574]
    });

    // view tilt controls
    var pitch = 0;
    function addLayer(name) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '#';
        link.className = 'active';
        link.textContent = name;

        link.onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if (e.target.textContent === "^") {
                if (pitch <=60) {
                    pitch +=5;
                    map.setPitch(pitch);
                    this.className = '';
                }
            } else {
                this.className = 'active';
                if (pitch > 0) {
                    pitch -= 5;
                    map.setPitch(pitch);
                }
            }
        };
        var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
        layers.appendChild(link);
    }
    addLayer('^');
    addLayer('v');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java class generating the pbf content:**

```
...
import no.ecc.vectortile.VectorTileEncoder;

public class GridTileSourceImpl implements TileSource {

    public byte[] getAsProtobuf(int zoom, int x, int y) throws TileSourceException {

        int dimension = DDSVectorTile.TILE_DIMENSION; // equals 16384, tried 4096 and 256
        int step = (dimension >= 16) ? dimension / 16 : dimension;

        VectorTileEncoder encoder = new VectorTileEncoder(dimension, 8, false);

        tileBorders(dimension, encoder);
        verticalLines(dimension, step, encoder);
        horizontalLines(dimension, step, encoder);

        return encoder.encode();
    }

    private void tileBorders(int dimension, VectorTileEncoder encoder) {
        Coordinate[] tileBorder = new Coordinate[4];
        tileBorder[0] = new Coordinate(0, 0);
        tileBorder[1] = new Coordinate(0, dimension);
        tileBorder[2] = new Coordinate(dimension, dimension);
        tileBorder[3] = new Coordinate(dimension, 0);
        encoder.addFeature("debug_line_red", Collections.emptyMap(),
                new GeometryFactory().createLineString(tileBorder));
    }

    private void horizontalLines(int dimension, int step, VectorTileEncoder encoder) {
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x += step) {
            Coordinate[] line = new Coordinate[2];
            line[0] = new Coordinate(x, 0);
            line[1] = new Coordinate(x, dimension);
            encoder.addFeature("debug_line_blue", Collections.emptyMap(),
                    new GeometryFactory().createLineString(line));

        }
    }

    private void verticalLines(int dimension, int step, VectorTileEncoder encoder) {
        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; y += step) {
            Coordinate[] line = new Coordinate[2];
            line[0] = new Coordinate(0, y);
            line[1] = new Coordinate(dimension, y);
            encoder.addFeature("debug_line_green", Collections.emptyMap(),
                    new GeometryFactory().createLineString(line));

        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**:

Desktop browser - all fine:

[image: Desktop browser - all fine]

Mobile browser - lines disappear:

[image: Mobile browser - lines disappear]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a functional demo using your generated vector tiles.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this issue?